# Prevent external editing of an Application Manifest?

Tags: delphi, manifest

I have a Delphi application which contains a manifest file with a few dependencies on external assemblies. Is there anyway to prevent someone from updating/changing that manifest to point to different assemblies, thereby perhaps changing the way my app works? Using MT.exe it's pretty easy to update an embedded manifest.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about someone changing your embedded manifests using an resource editor. If you worry about that you should start worrying about every single method you're importing (because someone might edit your exe's import tables), not to mention worrying about someone editing your embedded DFM files (those changing your application's look or functionality)

Comment: I think this defeats one of the objectives of manifests. The manifest indicates at the time you wrote the application, the known compatible dependencies. If at a later stage new compatible dependencies are found, you (or someone else) only needs to change the manifest - not rebuild the application. Essentially, you'd be preventing this option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I suppose you could read the manifest resource at startup and then terminate the process if it didn't match what you expect it to be.  You might check against a hashed version to make it a little harder for someone to defeat the test.

But if someone really wants to defeat this sort of test then they'll find a way.

Comment: Editing a manifest (or a resource) is trivially easy.  Defeating code that is checking a checksummed manifest and preventing application execution if tampering is detected is certainly not impossible, but it's not's orders of magnitude more difficult.  This is why banks don't keep all their money sitting in a pile in the middle of the branches... sure, if someone is determined enough they can steal it from the vault, but it still makes sense to protect what you can, if it suits your needs to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that if you sign your EXE (EXE contains the embedded manifest) with a certificate, then it should be possible to stop external edits to the manifest.  Of course, getting a certificate isn't the easiest or cheapest process.

Comment: couldn't the exe be unsigned?

Comment: The signature could be stripped, but you could add code to the exe that checks for the signature.  Then someone could tweak your binary to skip the checking code, so you add more code to protect against that, and... well, you get the idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the manifest as a resource compiled into the application and write it to your directory as part of your startup process.  This will overwrite any changes that anyone might have made and keep you in control.

Comment: during startup is too late and resources are editable which is the point of the question